# Computation of a matrix exponential for general dimensions

Tags: matrices

Originally I wanted to prove something else then I hit on this question that I find quite interesting but I don't know how to prove it elegantly.

Let $$J=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & I \\ -I & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}$$ with I the identity matrix in an appropriate dimension. Then the matrix-exponential is given by $$e^{\nu J t}=\begin{pmatrix}
 COS & SIN \\ -SIN & COS
 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $COS$ is the matrix with $\cos(\nu t)$ on its diagonals, i.e. $$COS=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\nu t) & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & 0 \\ 0 & \dots & \cos(\nu t) \end{pmatrix} $$ and $SIN$ analogue. $\nu$ is a scalar.

I noticed it in two and four dimensions and computed it for higher dimensions in Matlab, see at the picture.
[image]

Of course it could be that it works only for lower dimensions but I doubt that. Now to the proof. I can only imagine a quite extensive proof. I can show you my approach.

The matrix exponential can be computed by using the transformation $J=S N S^{-1}$ where N is the Jordan Normalform of J and S the matrix with the eigenvectors.

Let $J \in \mathbb{R^{2n}}$, then its JNF is given by the matrix with $n$ times $i$ and $n$ times $-i$ on the diagonals, i.e. all eigenvalues are algebraically simple. Now to the eigenvectors, they are always complex conjugated to another one. But I don't want to compute them if it is not necessary.

Another approach would be the definition of the exponential function, i.e. $$e^{\nu Jt}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\nu J t)^m}{m!}$$

Maybe someone has a more elegant proof.

Best regards,
Marvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this just reduces to the case where $J = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, nothing interesting is happening in the higher dimensions.

Comment: Okay thank you. The structure seems to hold in higher dimensions. I thought of a formal proof that worked for 2-dim and I just noticed that it also works for n-dim, I think. 

$e^{\nu J t}$ solves the linear Diff.eq. $\dot X(t)= \nu J X(t), X(0)=I$  and it has a unique solution. Now it is easy to show that the matrix with COS and SIN also solves this diff.eq.
Thank you.